# How to display search string and replace string in a dialogue box using vim

Tags: vim

How to display search string and replace string in a dialogue box using vim.
The below code is only used for search and replace string. My requirement is  while replacing the string matching lines and replacement should be display in a dialogue box. Is it possible ?

```
:%s/\\docume.*/\\docmentstring\[test]{packages}/gec
```

Comment: well I am a terminal vim user, I haven't seen vim has any "dialog box".  And if there was, it makes editing slower. since you have to somehow "close" the dialog box, totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

The `c` flag in a search/replace operation (which you've specified) causes vim to confirm each substitution. It does this via a text prompt, not a GUI dialog box. It cannot be made to use GUI dialog box at all (short of, you know, hacking on the source). This is the vim way to confirm every substitution.

When vim is running with a GUI enabled, the `inputdialog()` function can be used to prompt for a text string via  GUI dialog. Thus, in theory one could build a search/replace replacement function out of the `search()` and `substitute()` functions that uses `inputdialog()` to prompt with a dialog box for every replacement. However, it would be ugly and clunky as you'd still be typing in responses and not clicking buttons. It's not very vim-like and would be a rather unpleasant experience.